# rmarkdown execution of code inside a variable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rscript

I have code similar to the following, which is dynamically generated and stored in a variable:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "3 June 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, comment=""}
for (i in 1 :  3) { 
  cat('\n') 
  print(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, "Sepal.Length"] ))
}
```
````

Let's say it's stored in a variable named `rmkdown_code`

Now, I need to be able to execute the code in this variable and render it as html or pdf. I am aware of the `results = asis` options, and I've tried different variations of it. But still, I'm not able to get the above code to render in html.  The html page comes up in rstudio, and it shows the contents of `rmkdown_code` variable.  It's just not executing it.

I need the content of `rmkdown_code` to be rendered as though it was from a flat file.

I have tried the following, none of which worked.  Some formatted the text better, but the graph is not plotted.  I would like to avoid writing the content of the `rmkdown_code` variable to a flat file.

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE}
knitr::knit_expand(text=rmkdown_code)

#eval(parse(text = rmkdown_code))
#eval(c(paste0("- `", rmkdown_code, "`"), sep = "\n"))
#eval(knitr::asis_output(rmkdown_code))
#res <- knitr::knit_expand(text=rmkdown_code);knitr::knit(text=res, quiet=F)
# knitr::inline_expr("2+2")
```
````

output of `dput(rmarkdown)`:

````
## "---\ntitle: \"test\"\nauthor: \"me\"\ndate: \"3 June 2019\"\noutput: html_document\n---\n\n```{r setup, include=FALSE}\nknitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)\n```\n\n```{r, comment=\"\"}\nfor (i in 1 :  3) { \n  cat('\\n') \n  print(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, \"Sepal.Length\"] ))\n}\n```\n"
````

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `dput(rmarkdown_code)`? It's not clear how the code is stored in a variable.

Comment: @Matt I've updated the original post with the details.  is there anything else i can provide?

Comment: Is the variable an `expression` or a `character` string of code?  **EDIT**: Just saw your update and it appears to be the latter.

Comment: @Greg did you have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as my background in this particular area is purely academic and lacking in experience.  In fact, I'm very interested to see any answers that might come up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, not sure if it's ideal for your use case but it does successfully render `rmkdown_code` as an HTML report.

Be sure that you set your working directory or are working in a project, because the .rmd will render to your current wd.

````
rmkdown_code <- "---\ntitle: \"test\"\nauthor: \"me\"\ndate: \"3 June 2019\"\noutput: html_document\n---\n\n```{r setup, include=FALSE}\nknitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)\n```\n\n```{r, comment=\"\"}\nfor (i in 1 :  3) { \n  cat('\\n') \n  print(summary(iris[i*50 : 50, \"Sepal.Length\"] ))\n}\n```\n"

render_func <- function(x){
  writeLines(x, "temp.rmd")
  rmarkdown::render("temp.rmd")
}

render_func(rmkdown_code)
````

This gives us:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  The problem with this answer is that it creates a temporary file.  I would very much like to avoid writing the variable content into any file.

Comment: I'm not sure of a way that `rmarkdown::render()` will work if the input isn't a `markdown` file. Is it possible to create a temp file on your C:/ drive and then automatically delete it?